# to_date unable to print timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-date

I want to print the timestamp from the below sql

```
select to_date('01/01/2011 12:00:00 AM','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') from dual;
```

current output --> `1/1/2011` (not printing the timestamp only for 12 am. if the min is 12:01 then it is printing.

but I need the output as `1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: When you say you want to print it, where do you want to print it? Is this in a report, a web page, sqlplus?

Answer (score 4):

`TO_DATE` converts a string to a `DATE`.  A `DATE` is stored in a packed binary format that is not human readable.  An Oracle `DATE` does not have a format.  So when you ask a program to display a date, it has to then convert the `DATE` to a string.  If you don't explicitly specify the format by doing an explicit `TO_CHAR`, a tool like SQL*Plus will convert the date to a string using the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.  Other applications may choose different ways to convert a date to a string-- using the client's regional settings, for example, or by allowing the user to configure the format.

If you want to return a string in a particular format that represents a `DATE`, you'd need to use an explicit `TO_CHAR`.  Something like

```
SELECT to_char( some_date_column, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM' )
  FROM some_table
```

In the specific case you posted, since you have the string in your hand as a string, you'd simply want to select it from dual rather than doing a `TO_DATE` to convert it to a date and then a `TO_CHAR` to convert it back to a string.  I'm assuming, though, that you have an actual `DATE` in the actual table that you are trying to select from.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to control the formatting is to use `to_char` and explicitly specify the date format you want.

```
select to_char(to_date('01/01/2011 12:00:00 AM','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'DD/MM/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') 
  from dual;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can Use

```
select  Convert(varchar,'01/01/2011 12:00:00 AM',113)
```

Comment: The question is tagged for Oracle and `TO_DATE` is Oracle syntax.  This is a SQL Server solution.